# Phong Illumination in OpenGL website

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

I was reading through the following Phong Illumination shader which has in opengl.org:

[Phong Illumination in Opengl.org](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/lighting.php)

The vertex and fragment shaders were as follows:

vertex shader:

```
 varying vec3 N;
 varying vec3 v;
 void main(void)  
 {     
   v = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);       
   N = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
   gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;  
 }
```

fragment shader:

```
varying vec3 N;
varying vec3 v;    
void main (void)  
{  
   vec3 L = normalize(gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz - v);   
   vec3 E = normalize(-v); // we are in Eye Coordinates, so EyePos is (0,0,0)  
   vec3 R = normalize(-reflect(L,N));  

   //calculate Ambient Term:  
   vec4 Iamb = gl_FrontLightProduct[0].ambient;    

   //calculate Diffuse Term:  
   vec4 Idiff = gl_FrontLightProduct[0].diffuse * max(dot(N,L), 0.0);
   Idiff = clamp(Idiff, 0.0, 1.0);     

   // calculate Specular Term:
   vec4 Ispec = gl_FrontLightProduct[0].specular 
                * pow(max(dot(R,E),0.0),0.3*gl_FrontMaterial.shininess);
   Ispec = clamp(Ispec, 0.0, 1.0); 
   // write Total Color:  
   gl_FragColor = gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor + Iamb + Idiff + Ispec;     
}
```

I was wondering about the way which he calculates the viewer vector or `v`. Because by multiplying the vertex position with `gl_ModelViewMatrix`, the result will be in view matrix (and view coordinates are rotated most of the time, compared to world coordinates).

So, we cannot simply subtract the light position from `v` to calculate the `L` vector, because they are not in the same coordinates system. Also, the result of dot product between L and N won't be correct because their coordinates are not the same. Am I right about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, we cannot simply subtract the light position from v to calculate
>   the L vector, because they are not in the same coordinates system.
>   Also, the result of dot product between L and N won't be correct
>   because their coordinates are not the same. Am I right about it?

No.

The `gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz` is *not* the value you set `GL_POSITION` to. The GL will automatically multiply the position by the current `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix at the time of the `glLight()` call. Lighting calculations are done completely in eye space in fixed-function GL. So both `V` and `N` have to be transformed to eye space, and `gl_LightSource[].position` will already be transformed to eye-space, so the code is correct and is actually not mixing different coordinate spaces.

The code you are using is relying on deprecated functionality, using lots of the old fixed-function features of the GL, including that particular issue. In mordern GL, those builtin uniforms and attributes do not exist, and you have to define your own - and you can interpret them as you like.

You of course could also ignore that convention and still use a different coordinate space for the lighting calculation with the builtins, and interpret `gl_LightSource[].position` differently by simply choosing some other matrix when setting a position (typically, the light's world space position is set while the `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix contains only the view transformation, so that the eye-space light position for some world-stationary light source emerges, but you can do whatever you like). However, the code as presented is meant to work as some "drop-in" replacement for the fixed-function pipeline, so it will interpret those builtin uniforms and attributes in the same way the fixed-function pipeline did.

Comment: Oh, I see. So, the `gl_NormalMatrix` contains the model_view matrix in old fixed-function pipeline and also the `gl_LightSource` are transformed in view coordinates. Then, the code is working.

Actually, I was checking the superbible opengl phong illumination shaders, and it was also doing the phong illumination computations in view coordinates.

Comment: @mmostajab: Well, `gl_NormalMatrix` is derived from the modelview matrix, it is not the same thing. The reason is that normals have to be transformed differently in some cases. Think of a "skew" operation. If you apply it to the normal directions dircetly, the resulting normals wouldn't enu up perpendicular to the surface anymore. (assuming they were before). A more thourough explanation for that is given [at this lighthouse3d tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/the-normal-matrix/).